# Distinct Paged List<Object> sorted on joined table

Tags: nhibernate, sorting, join

Been trying to get the following working using nhibernate HQL or QueryOver. I am trying to get a sorted DISTINCT list of the entity organisation while sorting on joined tables and using paging.
Entities are (shortened version):

Organisation

```
 OrganisationId
 Name
 StatusId
 SubstatusId
```

Address

```
 AddressId
 OrganisationId
 City
 CountryId
```

ListItem

```
 ListItemId
 Name
```

StatusId, SubstatusId and CountryId are foreign keys to ListItemId
ListItemId is a list of user entered options.
There can be more than one address for each organisation

To sort on Organisation.Address[x].Country.Name I need to include this in the select, but obviously then I dont get distinct organisations rather distinct organisations for a particular address.

I cant then get this into the nHibernate entity as it has the additional Country.Name field.

Also I cant run another distinct over the initial results as im using .SetFirstResult and .SetMaxResults to do SQL Paging.
If I only want 10 rows, then I initially get 10 rows of distinct (organisation + country name).
When i run another distinct over this will get reduced if an organisation has more than address.

Any ideas how to get a distinct paged list of organisations while sorting on Address.Name, Status.Name, SubStatus.Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with 2 selects and a bit of linq:

1. Do your projection selecting Organisation.Id, Address.Name, Status.Name, SubStatus.Name, ordering them appropriately and paging the results (well you just need to select Organisation.Id)
2. Do another query to load the organisations by the Id's in the previous projection
3. Combine the queries to order the list of organisations by their order in the first select

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I wouldnt have to do a second load based on the Ids since I would/should already have all the organisation data required from the original select, but i would also have the additional from the joined tables so i can sort by that. I cant seem to convert/cast that object[] of data into the nHibernate Entity as there is more data than the entity expects. I was thinking of adding 'hidden' columns to the organisation entity for the sort options and update those when the joined tables are updated. Messy and redundant, but speed is a higher priority than normalized data